# Modeling curved light in media with "complex" indices of refraction

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, computational-physics, refraction, algorithms

I've written an algorithm to solve the Time Difference of Arrival (TDoA) localization problem, using Bancroft's method ([see](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Bancroft_Method#:%7E:text=The%20Bancroft%20method%20allows%20obtaining,knowledge%20for%20the%20receiver%20location.)). Given the coordinates of $n$ nodes in `3 dimensions`, the velocity of some signal $v$, and the time of signal arrival at each node, I'm able to reconstruct the coordinates of the signal source, to a high degree of precision/accuracy, and fairly efficiently.

Now, I'd like to do the same, but where the signal is light, and the media in question has a "complex" index of refraction, in that it increases a function of depth. Therefore, of course, light takes a curved path through the medium. Preferably, I'd like to continue using Bancroft's method. In my case, I have only `4` receivers, which is too few to solve it (at all, or at best with any reasonable speed) using "common" methods (least squares, Newton-Raphson, etc).

My initial thought was to begin by fixing the speed of light at some "average" value, solve for the coordinates, compute the speed of light at that depth, then repeat with this new value. I'm not sure this will work, however, since that calculated speed is only valid at precisely that depth.

What can be done?

Comment: Suggestion: If the word _complex_ does not refer to complex numbers, consider to use another word.

Comment: You need a non-linear optics here. Check [Light propagation in
anisotropic media](https://www.fzu.cz/~kuzelp/Optics/Lecture8.pdf) and [Anisotropic media](http://www.physics.ttk.pte.hu/files/TAMOP/FJ_Nonlinear_Optics/6_anisotropic_media.html).